# Flutter : How to disable screenshot on iOS devices or just detect the action of screenshot

Tags: ios, flutter, screenshot

My problem is that I'am currently stuck and I can't block the screenshots on iOS devices in my flutter app even if I use this solution :

https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot_callback this package is depricated and I can't use it.

```
The plugin `screenshot_callback` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
```

and even adding a swift code doesn't work :

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
  
  // <Add>
  override func applicationWillResignActive(
    _ application: UIApplication
  ) {
    self.window.isHidden = true;
  }
  override func applicationDidBecomeActive(
    _ application: UIApplication
  ) {
    self.window.isHidden = false;
  }
  

}
```

Please let me know if you have any solutions to fix it :)

Comment: You can't block screenshots on iOS. You can listen for the `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot` notification, which is what that plug-in does.

Comment: Why is this question about iOS tagged with [android]?